# Register a custom post type as public = false, but have content appear in search engines?

Tags: theme-development

I dont want the pages to exist 
ie. they go to 404 if you attempt to access them but I want the content on to be indexed in a search, google, bing etc

the custom-post-type content will be displayed in a front page template,
in the style of a 'one page layout'.

like this site;
http://www.bingu.name/demo/wpmiworks/

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at the source code, you'll see how their site works. Basically, **all** content is queried and displayed in its own div on the page. But most content, except for the desired content, is hidden by default. And then jQuery is used to hide or show what is selected via the navigation. The hash tags also represent a direct link to a particular div. It's actually pretty simple.

Step 1. Query your posts/pages/custom post types depending on what you want displayed and put them in their own divs on the home page template. (Give each div a unique ID.)

Step 2. Set up your Javascript/jQuery to show/hide content based on what's requested. (They've only used basic jQuery animate functions to 'scroll to', 'hide' or 'show' a page/hidden div.)